# Difference between `type foo struct` and `type foo []struct`

Tags: go, types

What is the main difference between these structs?

```
type foo struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

and

```
type foo []struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

Comment: The first is a named struct type. The second is a named slice type whose elements are anonymous structs with the given fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
type foo1 struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type foo2 []struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

Simple understand as

```
type foo2 []foo1
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a struct type which is named. It can be initialized in the usual way:

```
// Initialize a foo
f1 := foo{"name1"}
// Initialize a foo slice
f1s := []foo {
  foo{"name2"},
  foo{"name3"},
}
```

The second is a named slice type whose elements are anonymous structs with the given fields. It can be initialized like this:

```
f2 := foo {
  {"name4"},
  {"name5"},
}
```